# Java 8 closures/lambda + Java EE 7 = LINQ or Grails-like magic in JPA?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, lambda, closures, java-8

One of the coolest things about Grails is that you can do something like

`MyDomainObject.findAll { foo == x && (bar == null || bar == y) }`

and the closure gets translated to a SQL WHERE clause.

I think C# LINQ allows something similar with expression trees, like

`list.Where(obj => obj.Field == value)`

Does anyone know if Java 8 and Java EE 7 will include support for similar magic in standard JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Java EE 7 will not include support for similar query in JPA 2.1 . 
but you can find a wide range of new JPQL functionality

Comment: What is "New JPQL functionality" - please elaborate?